# Number of HTTP requests in absolute time window (pie chart)

Tags: prometheus, grafana

We are using Prometheus 2.46.0 to scrape metrics every 30 seconds from our .NET Core application which exposes metrics using [prometheus-net](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net) NuGet package. One of the exposed metrics is a counter `http_requests_received_total`. Example values:

```
# HELP http_requests_received_total Provides the count of HTTP requests that have been processed by the ASP.NET Core pipeline.
# TYPE http_requests_received_total counter
http_requests_received_total{code="200",method="POST",controller="RestAPI",action="SendMail",page="",endpoint="MailService/RestAPI/SendMail"} 39
http_requests_received_total{code="302",method="GET",controller="Auth",action="Logout",page="",endpoint="{controller=MailService}/{action=Index}/{id?}"} 4
http_requests_received_total{code="302",method="GET",controller="MailService",action="Index",page="",endpoint="{controller=MailService}/{action=Index}/{id?}"} 2
http_requests_received_total{code="200",method="POST",controller="Auth",action="Login",page="",endpoint="{controller=MailService}/{action=Index}/{id?}"} 1
http_requests_received_total{code="200",method="GET",controller="Auth",action="Login",page="",endpoint="{controller=MailService}/{action=Index}/{id?}"} 7
```

We are using Grafana 10.1.0 to visualize number of requests grouped by `(controller, action)` in selected time interval in the upper right corner in Grafana. Note that the selected time interval can be **absolute** (ex. from `3-Dec-2023 11:45:15` until `4-Dec-2023 09:22:09`).

Currently, we are using the following query for Grafana pie chart:

```
sum(increase(http_requests_received_total[$__range])) by (controller, action)
```

Chart configuration is shown on the following image: [Chart configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55iCK.png). I marked the important parts.

Is our query in Grafana dashboard correct for our use-case (sum of requests grouped by `(controller, action)` in selected time interval)? Is Grafana pie chart configured correctly (Format = Time Series, Type = Range, Calculation (reducer function) = Last *)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is our query in Grafana dashboard correct for our use-case?

Yes, your query is correct.

> Is Grafana pie chart configured correctly (Format = Time Series, Type = Range, Calculation (reducer function) = Last *)?

Your configuration should produce correct results<sup>*</sup>. But it is not the most efficient way of achieving them. You can use Type *Instant* without any calculation (*All values*). This way Grafana will only request data for the last moment of time range selected, and no aggregation will be performed.

> Note that the selected time interval can be absolute

It doesn't matter. In terms of requesting data from data sources (Prometheus in this case) all time is absolute. Relative time is only there in timepickers for your, as a user, ease.

---

<sup>*</sup> : theoretically, calculation *Last** can result in an inconsistent results. If data is produced by multiple targets, and one of targets went down recently, it will be shown still (until time of last seen lefts selected time range). But I don't think this is a case for your situation.